# Resize text line on mobile (div)

Tags: css

Does anyone know to to resize text for mobile device? My CSS doesn't work.

```
<div class="wpb_column wpb_content_element how-it><div class="wpb_wrapper">
<h1 class="p1" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 45px;">
<span style="color: #000000;">SLIK FUNGERER ABONNEMENTET</span></span></h1></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
 @media (max-width: 360px) {
 .how-it h1 {font-size: 16px; !important;}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity to learn how CSS is applied according to the specified rules.

To the specific problem, you cannot override a style applied directly on an element by altering a descendant element. You need to target the same element that is styled.

So target the `span` element `.how-it h1 span{font-size: 16px; !important;}`

But the more correct way would be to remove the styles completely from the html and do both mobile and desktop styling through CSS rules. This way you could avoid using `!important` which will only cause more problems down the road when you want to restyle it according to other scenarios.